# Efficiently searching for prefixes, with wildcards and mismatches

Tags: python, string, algorithm, prefix, trie

Given a string `str` and a list of variable-length prefixes `p`, I want to find all possible prefixes found at the start of `str`, allowing for up to `k` mismatches and wildcards (dot character) in `str`.

I only want to search at the beginning of the string and need to do this efficiently for `len(p) <= 1000; k <= 5` and millions of `str`s.

So for example:

```
str = 'abc.efghijklmnop'
p = ['abc', 'xxx', 'xbc', 'abcxx', 'abcxxx']
k = 1

result = ['abc', 'xbc', 'abcxx'] #but not 'xxx', 'abcxxx'
```

Is there an efficient algorithm for this, ideally with a python implementation already available?

My current idea would be to walk through `str` character by character and keep a running tally of each prefix's mismatch count.

At each step, I would calculate a new list of candidates which is the list of prefixes that do not have too many mismatches.

If I reach the end of a prefix it gets added to the returned list.

So something like this:

```
def find_prefixes_with_mismatches(str, p, k):
    p_with_end = [prefix+'$' for prefix in p]
    candidates = list(range(len(p)))
    mismatches = [0 for _ in candidates]
    result = []

    for char_ix in range(len(str)):
        #at each iteration we build a new set of candidates
        new_candidates = []

        for prefix_ix in candidates:
            #have we reached the end?
            if p_with_end[prefix_ix][char_ix] == '$':
                #then this is a match
                result.append(p[prefix_ix])
                #do not add to new_candidates
            else:
                #do we have a mismatch
                if str[char_ix] != p_with_end[prefix_ix][char_ix] and str[char_ix] != '.' and p_with_end[prefix_ix][char_ix] != '.':
                    mismatches[prefix_ix] += 1
                    #only add to new_candidates if the number is still not >k
                    if mismatches[prefix_ix] <= k:
                        new_candidates.append(prefix_ix)
                else:
                    #if not, this remains a candidate
                    new_candidates.append(prefix_ix)

        #update candidates
        candidates = new_candidates

    return result
```

But I'm not sure if this will be any more efficient than simply searching one prefix after the other, since it requires rebuilding this list of candidates at every step.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of something that does exactly this.

But if I were to write it, I'd try constructing a trie of all possible decision points, with an attached vector of all states you wound up in.  You would then take each string, walk the trie until you hit a final matched node, then return the precompiled vector of results.

If you've got a lot of prefixes and have set `k` large, that trie may be very big.  But if you're amortizing creating it against running it on millions of strings, it may be worthwhile.